# How to invert triangle in asm

Tags: assembly, x86

I can not for the life of my figure this out. When I run this program the first two triangles output correctly however i'm having trouble with the third triangle.
What I'm trying to get is:

```
    *
  * *
* * *
```

But I can't seem to get the correct amount of spaces required and I keep ending up in a infinite loop.

```
org 100h


.data
Input db "Enter size of the triangle between 2 to 9: $" ;String to prompt the user
Size dw ?               ; variable to hold size of triangle
spot db " $" ; a space

.code
Main proc
Start:
Mov ah, 09h  ; function to display string
Mov dx, offset input ;prompts user for input
int 21h ;interrupt processor to call OS

mov ah, 01h ; DOG get character function #
int 21h; takes user input

sub al, '0' ; subtract ascii value of character zero

mov ah, 0   ;blank top half of ax reigster

mov size, ax ; we use ax instead of al because we used dw instead of db
mov cx, ax ; copy size into variable size and cx reigster     

mov bx, 1                    

call newline


lines:                 ; outer loop for number of lines
push cx
mov cx,bx





stars:                 ; inner loop to print stars

mov ah, 02h   
mov dl, '*'
int 21h


loop stars

inc bx

call newline
pop cx     ; get outer loop value back


loop lines
call newline  




; second triangle   

mov cx, size 
dec bx

lines2:  

push cx
mov cx,bx





stars2:
mov ah, 02h
mov dl, '*'
int 21h

loop stars2

 dec bx

 call newline
 pop cx
loop lines2 

;end 



call newline


 ; third triangle   
mov cx, size
inc bx    



lines3:
push cx
mov cx,bx
spaces:
mov ah, 09h 
mov dx, offset spot
int 21h    

stars3:
mov ah, 02h
mov dl, '*'
int 21h     



loop stars3  
loop spaces       
 inc bx      
 call newline  
 pop cx

loop lines3 
;end   


main endp   


proc newline
mov ah, 02h        ; go to a new line after input
mov dl, 13
int 21h
mov dl, 10
int 21h

ret ;returns back


newline endp

end main
```

Comment: Walk thru this with me. When you hit `second triangle`, what values are in `size` and bx?  If you entered 3, then size should be 3, and ebx should also be 3 (is that right?). First thing you do is `dec bx` (2). Then you print bx stars. Then you `dec bx` (1) and loop around to print the second line of stars. You print bx stars and `dec bx` (0) and loop around to print the third line of stars.  But since bx is zero, how many stars are you going to print (remember, `loop` decrements cx, *then* checks for 0)? Walking thru this with a debugger might make this clearer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your jumps and loops are not in the correct order, and the blank spaces require their own counter, so I fixed the third triangle section :

```
lines3:

mov bp, size   ;<====== BP USED AS BLANK SPACE COUNTER.
sub bp, bx     ;<====== MINUS ASTERISK COUNTER.
jz  no_spaces  ;<====== IF BP IS ZERO, SKIP SPACES.
spaces:
mov ah, 09h 
mov dx, offset spot
int 21h    
dec bp        ;<======= DECREASE COUNTER.
jnz spaces    ;<======= IF COUNTER NOT ZERO, REPEAT.

no_spaces:

push cx
mov cx,bx
stars3:
mov ah, 02h
mov dl, '*'
int 21h      
loop stars3  

call newline
inc bx      
pop cx
loop lines3 
;end
```